# Status bar notification opens the activity when phone start

Tags: android, service, android-activity, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I have created a service which displays a status bar notification after certain time interval.
I also have created broadcast receiver which starts the service when phone restarts or power on. The problem I am facing is that when phone restarts , I see the notification in bar, but after that the application launches. I don't want the application to launch itself, it should only launch when user clicks on the notification.

My code for Broad Cast Receiver:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {


            try
            {
                Intent intent1 = new  Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
                context.startService(intent1);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }


        }

    }
```

My code for notification is :

```
public static void showNotification(Context context )
    {


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)         context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Pull Me Down!!", 1000);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,X.class);
    PendingIntent  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "I came!!", "My First Notifcation" , pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(MY_ID, notification);

    }
```

I am calling above method in `onCreate` of my Service. and also calling it in my X activity class:

```
NotificationService.setActivity(StatusBarNotificationActivity.this);
                startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationService.class));
```

But don't know why when phone starts notification is show but after few seconds the X activity also launches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, just declared the `NotificationManager` and `Notification` outside the method, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use "Foreground service". To use foreground service you just need to call startForeground method.

```
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

But you have to control the service life-cycle if you don't want the notification always shows on the status bar. Hope this answer is helpful to you. :)